# Weak star cluster points of a sequence in the dual space

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $X^*$ its dual (space of continuous linear functionals $f: X\to \mathbb{R})$.  Let $ S_X$ and $B_X$ be the unit sphere and closed unit ball of $X$ respectively. Suppose $(y^*_n)$ is a sequence in $B_{X^*}$ and $(y_m)$ is a sequence in $S_X$ satisfying $y^*_n(y_m)\geq 1-\frac{1}{n}$ for all $m\geq n.$ If $y^*$ is a weak star cluster point of $(y^*_n)$, then how can we say that $y^*(y_m)$ converges to 1?

This is discussed on page 176 [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/268641467_Rotund_points_nested_sequence_of_balls_and_smoothness_in_Banach_spaces).
And I am not getting how this can be done. If we let $n\to \infty$, then $m$ also tends to infinity.

Comment: As stated, this is false. For example, let $X = C([0, 1])$, $y_n^*$ be evaluation at $1/n$, and $y_m$ be any norm 1 continuous function which is 1 on $[1/m, 1]$ and 0 at 0. Then $y^*$ is evaluation at 0, so $y^*(y_m) = 0$ for all $m$.

Comment: @DavidGao Could you please explicitly write the definition of the evaluation map $y^*_n$ at $\frac{1}{n}?$

Comment: $y_n^*(f) = f(1/n)$.